# how to update database with list element?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to update my database every 60 seconds with list elements, I tried this code:

```
   import pymysql
   import random
   import time
   t=[random.randint(1,21) , random.randint(0,99) , random.randint(1,21) , random.randint(1,100)]
   while True:
       conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", db="LEDS")
       myCursor = conn.cursor()
       myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA1=t[0]")
       myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA2=t[1]")
       myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA3=t[2]")
       myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA4=t[3]")
       time.sleep(60)
       conn.commit()
       conn.close()
```

I am new with MySQL anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that list values you are passing are not really list values. Since you have passed them as a pure string, this will not execute properly. You should probably change the code inside your while loop to something like this :

```
while True:
   conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", db="LEDS")
   myCursor = conn.cursor()
   myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA1=%i", (t[0],))
   myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA2=%i", (t[1],))
   myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA3=%i", (t[2],))
   myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA4=%i", (t[3],))
```

The problem with the code you provided is that you're not passing the value of the list element since you're not referring to it in your code. Hope this helps.

EDIT : Updated the answer to protect against SQL Injection, per [Dylan Goldsborough](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8776734/dylan-goldsborough)

Comment: It is good to note that `pymysql` can also handle the formatting for you, which will protect against SQL injection. The syntax for `pymysql` seems to be `myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA1=%i", (t[0],))`.

Comment: That's actually the better way to do it. I will update. Thank you

Comment: I gett error with this method:
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: You should take the statments `conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", db="LEDS")` and `myCursor = conn.cursor()` out of the loop.

Comment: You need to use '%s' as the parameter place holder.

Comment: All 4 of your UPDATE statements are attempting to update the same column, CAMERA1.

Answer (score 1):

```
with pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", db="LEDS") as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as myCursor:
        while True:
            myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA1=%s", (t[0],))
            myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA2=%s", (t[1],))
            myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA3=%s", (t[2],))
            myCursor.execute("UPDATE DATA SET CAMERA4=%s", (t[3],))
            conn.commit()
            time.sleep(60)
```

If this is being executed concurrently by multiple tasks, then you should put the acquiring and releasing of the connection back in the loop. But here I am working under the assumption that there is only a single instance of this code being run, so only one connection is being tied up.